# Can I show all possible results in Search Result Web Part?

Tags: 2013, search, search-results, refinement-panel

I have a web part page with three web parts:

- Search Box
- Search Results
- Refinement

When I load the page, I get the "Nothing here matches your search" in the Search Results web part and the "We don't have any refiners to show you" in the Refinement Web Part.

What I would like is to display all possible results by default and then refine those based on user input (essentially, using search box input as just another refiner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search Results web part can be configured with pre-built queries by editing the web part properties and specifying the query. You can use * as query which attempts to return all matching results.